# error C1105: cannot call a non-function

Tags: opengl, glsl

I used a shader which worked in another program (in the same environment afaik) which can't compile now for some reason:

```
// Vertex Shader
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
out vec2 fragmentUV;
uniform mat4 ortho_matrix;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = ortho_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);
    fragmentUV = vertexUV;
}

// Fragment Shader
#version 330 core
in vec2 fragmentUV;
uniform sampler2D texture;
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color.rgba = texture(texture, fragmentUV).rgba;
}
```

It's a super basic shader and now it starts to throw errors all of the sudden.

Windows 8.1
Nvidia GeForce 1080 (this one is new maybe that's the problem?)

This is whats being output by Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color.rgba = texture(texture, fragmentUV).rgba;
}
```

I'm amazed this compiled at all in a different setting. You've named your texture the same as the function used to make texture lookups. You need to rename `uniform sampler2D texture;` to something else.

Comment: Now that I think about it was quite obvious but I'm still new to GLSL. Thanks, I'll check your answer as soo as I can.